# Apache Solr query not working properly

Tags: java, solr

Query not working with using `HttpSolrClient.query(core, query)`

core: `apparel-Product`

query: `q=autosuggest_en:cap&qt=/suggest&spellcheck.dictionary=en&spellcheck.q=cap`

Response : `{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=1},spellcheck={suggestions={},collations={}}}`

But same query getting result from rest with URL

http://localhost:8983/solr/apparel-Product/select?indent=on&q=autosuggest_en:cap&qt=/suggest&spellcheck.dictionary=en&spellcheck.q=cap&wt=json

Comment: Which version of solrj are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you mean you are passing a string like

```
q=autosuggest_en:cap&qt=/suggest&spellcheck.dictionary=en&spellcheck.q=cap
```

in the query object? You cannot do that, you need to set the other params separately (qt, spellcheck etc).

Have a look at [this method](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrRequest.html#setQueryParams(java.util.Set)) for example, and look around for some samples.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass Solr query parameters to [`SolrQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html) object concatenating them as they were in query string, use the `SolrQuery` object methods.

This example should fit your requirement:

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient("http://my-solr-server:8983/solr");

SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();

solrQuery.setQuery("utosuggest_en:cap"); // q parameter
solrQuery.setRequestHandler("/suggest"); // qt parameter
solrQuery.setParam("spellcheck.dictionary", "en"); // spellcheck.dictionary parameter
solrQuery.setParam("spellcheck.q", "cap"); // spellcheck.dictionary parameter

client.query("apparel-Product", solrQuery)
```